# Training and testing model of Chinese sentiment analysis model based on pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import torch.nn as nn

data = pd.read_csv("最终数据集.csv")
X = data.drop("Label", axis=1)  
X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=['Tokenized_Text'])  
input_size = X_encoded.shape[1]
hidden_size = 64
output_size = 3  

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

try:
    model = MyModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load("my_model.pth", map_location=torch.device('cpu')))

except (FileNotFoundError, KeyError):
    print("无法加载模型，请检查模型文件。")
    exit()

text = input("请输入要进行情感分类的文本：")

input_data = pd.DataFrame({"text": [text]})

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_input = vectorizer.fit_transform(input_data["text"]).toarray()

X_input = torch.tensor(X_input, dtype=torch.float32)

with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = model(X_input)

predicted_label = torch.argmax(y_pred, dim=1).item()  # 修改为在dim=1维度上找到最大值的索引

label_map = {2: "负面", 0: "中性", 1: "正面"}

print("预测结果：", label_map.get(predicted_label, "未知"))
```

训练模型的代码：

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class MyDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, X, y):
self.X = torch.tensor(X.values.astype(float), dtype=torch.float).to(device)
self.y = torch.tensor(y.values.astype(float), dtype=torch.float).to(device)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.X[idx], self.y[idx]

class MyModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
super(MyModel, self).__init__()
self.fc = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc(x)
        return out

data = pd.read_csv("最终数据集.csv")
print(data.columns)

X = data.drop("Label", axis=1)  # 特征矩阵，假设label列是标签列，需要从特征矩阵中去除
X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=\['Tokenized_Text'\])  # 对包含字符串的列进行独热编码
y = data\["Label"\]  # 标签向量

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_encoded, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

train_dataset = MyDataset(X_train, y_train)
test_dataset = MyDataset(X_test, y_test)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32)

input_size = X_encoded.shape\[1\]
hidden_size = 64
output_size = 1

model = MyModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
train_loss = 0.0
model.train()  # 设置模型为训练模式
for inputs, labels in train_loader:
optimizer.zero_grad()
inputs = inputs.to(device)
labels = labels.to(device)
outputs = model(inputs)
loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), labels)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
train_loss += loss.item() \* inputs.size(0)
train_loss /= len(train_loader.dataset)

    test_loss = 0.0
    model.eval()  # 设置模型为评估模式
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in test_loader:
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), labels)
            test_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
        test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    
    # 打印训练过程中的损失和测试集上的损失
    print("Epoch [{}/{}], Train Loss: {:.4f}, Test Loss: {:.4f}".format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, train_loss, test_loss))

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'my_model.pth')
```

报错：
`D:\Anaconda3\python.exe D:\pycharm目录\毕设\测试模型.py
请输入要进行情感分类的文本：今天天气真好
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pycharm目录\毕设\测试模型.py", line 51, in <module>
y_pred = model(X_input)
File "C:\Users\31328\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\pycharm目录\毕设\测试模型.py", line 21, in forward
out = self.fc1(x)
File "C:\Users\31328\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\31328\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 114, in forward
return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x1 and 42765x64)

进程已结束，退出代码为 1`

Let its dimensions be the same, the matrix can be multiplied, can make my project run smoothly, thank you

Comment: Please translate this into English